# How do I combine these two py2exe programs. They are pygame2exe and a pyttsx.exe

Tags: python, pygame, py2exe

I'm sorry if I asked the question in a funny way but, I did not know a better way to word it. I'm trying to combine this.

http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe?parent=CookBook

With this.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

py2exe_options = { 'includes': ['pyttsx.drivers.sapi5', 'win32com.gen_py.C866CA3A-32F7-11D2-9602-     00C04F8EE628x0x5x4'],
               'typelibs': [('{C866CA3A-32F7-11D2-9602-00C04F8EE628}', 0, 5, 4)] }

setup(console=['main.py'], options = {'py2exe': py2exe_options})
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help. everything I tried gives an error.
Thanks friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the pygame2exe script that you linked, you need to add the list of extra includes `['pyttsx.drivers.sapi5', 'win32com.gen_py.C866CA3A-32F7-11D2-9602-00C04F8EE628x0x5x4']` to the setup options used - it looks like you can do that by overriding or changing `self.extra_scripts = []` in `BuildExe`. You then also need to do something similar with your `typelibs`, thought it looks like pygame2exe doesnt support that directly.

The easiest thing for you to do would probably be to take a local copy of the pygame2exe and then modify the BuildExe class to add your specific options to this:

From:

```
options = {'py2exe': {'optimize': 2, 'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True, \
    'excludes': self.exclude_modules, 'packages': self.extra_modules, \
    'dll_excludes': self.exclude_dll,
    'includes': self.extra_scripts} },
```

To (this might need further tweaking:

```
options = {'py2exe': {'optimize': 2, 'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True, \
    'excludes': self.exclude_modules, 'packages': self.extra_modules, \
    'dll_excludes': self.exclude_dll,
    'includes': self.extra_scripts + ['pyttsx.drivers.sapi5', 'win32com.gen_py.C866CA3A-32F7-11D2-9602-00C04F8EE628x0x5x4'],
    'typelibs': [('{C866CA3A-32F7-11D2-9602-00C04F8EE628}', 0, 5, 4)]
}},
```

Let me know how you get on!

Comment: In that case, please can you accept the answer as correct. You're welcome.

Comment: I thought I did O_o =O

Comment: I think you must have done it at the same time that I commented - thanks.